# What CAPTCHA system is compatible with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, captcha

What [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) system is compatible with ASP.NET MVC? Are there any good examples out there?

Comment: NuGet **Google reCAPTCHA V2** for MVC 4 and 5

- [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reCAPTCH.MVC/)
- [Demo And Document](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Try this post](http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/03/aspnet-mvc-captcha/)

Source code can be found here if you don't have the patience to read the article: [zip file](http://www.coderjournal.com/uploads/2008/03/captcha.zip)

Comment: Newest article and code here:
http://nickberardi.com/actionfilterattribute-aspnet-mvc-captcha/
http://coderjournal.com/uploads/2008/03/mvc-preview-2-captcha1.zip

Answer (score 14):

This is a [**great** tutorial on using reCaptcha in MVC](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx) and works with the currently newest release.

Comment: This was a good tutorial. I used this as the basis of creating my own HTML Helper. The only thing I don't like about my solution is that I assign the captcha is valid value to the ViewBag in the ActionFilter and then examine it in the Controller Action. I would like it to be enough to decorate the action with the ActionFilter attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow, which is written using ASP.NET MVC, uses [reCAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA). You can find out more about reCAPTCHA at *[Digitizing Books One Word at a Time](http://recaptcha.net/learnmore.html)* and even [watch Jeff Atwood talk about reCAPTCHA within Stack Overflow](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC21/) during his talk at [PDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_Developers_Conference) 2008.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [RecaptchaMvc](http://weblogs.asp.net/awilinsk/archive/2008/12/09/recaptchamvc.aspx). It's a framework that uses the reCAPTCHA service and ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Would you mind sharing those few lines of code?