# ASP.NET MVC CAPTCHA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What CAPTCHA system is compatible with ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258897/what-captcha-system-is-compatible-with-asp-net-mvc)

I'm looking for a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) control that is designed for ASP.NET MVC.

Which one is the easiest to implement?

Answer (score 5):

reCAPTCHA- [see here on how to use it](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MVC Captcha](http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/03/aspnet-mvc-captcha/).