# Can you recommend a CAPTCHA library for use with an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, captcha

If you've incorporated CAPTCHA into an ASP.NET MVC application, did you use an external CAPTCHA library of some kind?  If so, would you recommend it and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use Captcha in asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286688/how-to-use-captcha-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 4):

1. do you use nuget? if you don't, right click on the reference section of your project and choose ad library package reference
2. get to the online tab, and install Microsoft Web Helpers dll
3. In this refrence, you will find a very handy helper which is ReCaptcha.GetHtml

you can use it on your view as like below;

```
@ReCaptcha.GetHtml(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["recaptcha-public-key"], "white")
```

I keep my recaptcah keys inside web.config so I used ConfigurationManager.AppSettings to reach them. You can get your own public and private keys from http://www.google.com/recaptcha

In your controller, it is very easy to handle the legitimate call like below;

```
if (ReCaptcha.Validate(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["recaptcha-private-key"])) { 

//the call is legitimate

} else {

// the call is not legitimate

}
```

I hope this helps.

**Update 1**
Uppps. don't forget to put the private and public keys inside you _ViewStart.cshtml file like below;

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ReCaptcha.PrivateKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["recaptcha-private-key"];
    ReCaptcha.PublicKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["recaptcha-public-key"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For an easy customisable one I would use: http://xcaptcha.codeplex.com/

For a standard complex one use: http://mvcrecaptcha.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lee Smit.  I would recommend using MVCRecaptcha (https://mvcrecaptcha.codeplex.com/).

You can also download the package from Nuget, however, make SURE that you don't download the other Recaptcha packages that are available - you should specifically download MVC recaptcha.

Then follow the rest of the instructions on the MVC recaptcha codeplex site to get up and running.