# Please provide some good captcha link to use in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a CAPTCHA that is compatible with ASP.NET MVC ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258897/what-is-a-captcha-that-is-compatible-with-asp-net-mvc)

Please provide some good captcha link to use in asp.net mvc

Comment: Search? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+captcha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some useful links for using captcha in asp.net mvc

1. http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx
2. http://xcaptcha.codeplex.com/